# import a list of modules

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have some plugin-system where all plugins can simply be added to a folder.

Now I import them manually, like this:

```
# main.py
from modules.AA import aa
from modules.BB import bb
from modules.CC import cc
from modules.DD import dd
...
```

But I would like to make this more dynamic, so I can just import all in a list `['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd',... ]`

folderstructure:

```
main.py
 /modules/__init__.py
 /modules/AA.py
 /modules/BB.py
 /modules/CC.py
...
```

I could add this to

`__init__.py` : `__all__ = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']`

but then I have to call the function like `AA.aa()`

What is needed to simply be able to call `aa()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `main.py`, you can use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#exec) on a formatted string with the elements in your list, for example:

```py
attributes = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']

for attribute in attributes:
    exec(f'from modules.{attribute.upper()} import {attribute}')
```

If the module names cannot be derived from the names of the attributes, you can of course use separate lists (or a `dict` if you prefer):

```py
modules = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD']
attributes = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']

for module, attribute in zip(modules, attributes):
    exec(f'from modules.{module} import {attribute}')
```

Comment: yes, that true :)  But these file and functionnames where just made up for this example. I could however do something like `exec(f'from modules.{module} import {module}')`